# PowerShell and WinApi

Tags: powershell, winapi

I was trying this:

```
$signature = @'
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
public static extern int ShellExecuteW(
  int    hwnd,
  string lpOperation,
  string lpFile,
  string lpParameters,
  string lpDirectory,
  int     nShowCmd
);
'@

$exec = Add-Type -memberDefinition $signature -name "win" -namespace Win32Functions -passThru

$exec::ShellExecuteW(0, "open", "notepad.exe", 0, 0, 1)
```

but the notepad does not start. How do I write this down correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate fix is twofold:

- `[DllImport("shell32.dll")]` ->
  `[DllImport("Shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]`

  - Since you explicitly target `ShellExecuteW` - the *Unicode* version of the API function - you must declare that fact via the `CharSet` field in the attribute. Once you do, you could actually *omit* the `W` suffix.<sup>[1]</sup>
  - `int    hwnd` must be `IntPtr    hwnd`.
- `$exec::ShellExecuteW(0, "open", "notepad.exe", 0, 0, 1)` ->
  `$exec::ShellExecute(0, "open", "notepad.exe", [NullString]::Value, [NullString]::Value, 1)`

  - Note the use of `[NullString]::Value` to pass `null` to the `string`-typed parameters; by default, PowerShell treats `$null` in a string context as the *empty string* rather than `null`; in this particular case, however, the empty string (and therefore `$null`) would work too.

To put it all together:

```bash
$exec = Add-Type -name "win" -namespace Win32Functions -passThru -memberDefinition @'
[DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int ShellExecuteW(
  IntPtr hwnd,
  string lpOperation,
  string lpFile,
  string lpParameters,
  string lpDirectory,
  int    nShowCmd
);
'@

$exec::ShellExecuteW(
  0, 
  'open', 
  'notepad.exe', 
  [NullString]::Value, 
  [NullString]::Value, 
  1
)
```

---

Taking a step back: The [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) cmdlet allows you to do the same without the need for on-demand-compiled P/Invoke declarations:

```bash
# Use -WorkingDirectory, if  needed.
Start-Process Notepad.Exe -Verb Open -WindowStyle Normal
```

---

<sup>[1] Omitting the `W` suffix (`ShellExecute`) while *not* specifying a `CharSet` value defaults to the *ANSI* version of the function. Using the `W` suffix *alone* - without `CharSet=CharSet.Unicode` - is *not* enough.</sup>